# Google Cloud Platform error when cloning repo from bitbucket

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, bitbucket, google-cloud-source-repos

I'm getting error like the image below when trying to clone repo from bitbucket. Got the same error when using github. Anyone ever encounter this problem?

> The server failed to process your request because of a conflicting
>   operation. Please try again.

[image: Error cloning repo from bitbucket]

Comment: How are you cloning the repository? Have you [set up the repository](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/setting-up-repositories) in GCP and follow [cloning documentation](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/cloning-a-repository)?

Comment: Yes and Yes. But still got the error result.

Comment: Clone operation creates a local Git repository based on your Cloud repository. If your main repository is already hosted at Github or Bitbucket you should automatically mirror it. Follow the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/connecting-hosted-repositories#connecting_a_repository).

Answer (score 0):

Clone operation creates a local Git repository based on your Cloud repository. If your main repository is already hosted in Github or Bitbucket you should automatically mirror it. Follow the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/connecting-hosted-repositories#connecting_a_repository).